# Kotlin/LayoutInflater with viewBinding

Tags: java, kotlin, layout-inflater, android-viewbinding

I'm new to the Kotlin programming language. I have some questions regarding RecyclerView and ViewBinding. My English might not be good. I am sorry for that. But I will do my best to explain. I would love it if you could answer my questions. Please read the questions, looking the images

[Questions are inside the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGEyA.jpg)

https://github.com/atilsamancioglu/K10-KotlinLandmarkBook

I don't know how to put the codes here differently. I am giving you the githup link